# Can we provide values for WSO2 ESB Throttling mediator dynamically at run time or can we modify the values of policy parameters dynamically?

Tags: wso2, throttling, wso2-esb

There is a requirement to load the throttling configuration parameters dynamically instead of configuring it through console or through policy.

What are the ways to do it? Is it possible to rewrite the policy file dynamically, as the throttling configurations will be as a policy once created.

Answer (score 0):

The throttling condition (called policy) of the [Throttle Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Throttle+Mediator) can be

1. modified inline over the Management Console
2. or taken from the registry. In the registry you can modify the policy too

But other possibilities do not exist out of the box. You would have to do a custom implementation or extension of the throttle mediator.